# What made the `ls` command available on Windows? (IronRuby and Rails Installer.)

Tags: windows, ironruby, windows-console, railsinstaller, railsinstaller-windows

I'm completely new to Ruby (and thus Rails) and I'm going through Hartl's second edition. Sorry in advance to ask such a novice question; I'm really inexperienced with Windows command-line.

I'm confused by the fact that the command-line session that I used to get through the basics (bundle install, git, Heroku, etc.) "knows" the `ls` command, but a new command-line session doesn't.

Exactly which step between [Rails Installer (Windows)](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-rails_installer_windows) and the end of chapter 1 made that tool (and I imagine other UNIX-like commands) available?

I'd `which ls` on my original session but of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ls command is distributed together with the other basic linux cli tools in the git bundle and located in RailsInstaller\Git\bin

Comment: Not sure why I didn't accept this immediately; sorry, and thanks!